# How to set include directories

Tags: cmake

I have a directory with various pre-built libraries (mostly headers and libs/dlls, all built without CMake or copied without installing using CMake). For my next project i want to use these libraries with CMake.

I am writing a script that iterates over all the libraries and generates the needed `<name>Config.cmake` and `<name>ConfigVersion.cmake` files referencing the existing directory structure.

A minimal config file may look like:

```
SET(ROOT_DIR_MYLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../MyLib")

add_library(MyLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${ROOT_DIR_MYLIB}/include"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${ROOT_DIR_MYLIB}/Lib/MyLib.lib"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${ROOT_DIR_MYLIB}/Lib/MyLibd.lib"
)
```

I have copied the line where the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is set from another project where this worked, but for some reason it does not for MyLib. When i attempt to include its header files i get compile errors that the include files can not be found.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Personally I prefer `target_include_directories(INTERFACE)`. Are you sure the path is correct though? You could check by converting to an absolute path and printing the result: `get_filename_component(ROOT_DIR_MYLIB_ABSOLUTE ${ROOT_DIR_MYLIB} ABSOLUTE) message("ROOT_DIR_MYLIB_ABSOLUTE  = ${ROOT_DIR_MYLIB_ABSOLUTE}")`

Comment: The path is correct. `target_include_directories` does not work in this case, i get the message `Cannot specify include directories for target "MyLib" which is not built`.

Comment: is MyLib your "new project" or a "pre-built library"?

Comment: It's a pre-built library that is built without cmake but i want to use it within a new cmake project.